# How do I set up PXE boot so that it failsover to another server when a MAC address is unrecognized?

Tags: linux, windows, pxe-boot, wds, cobbler

We want to automate our OS installations. We currently have Linux and Windows boxes. We already use Cobbler for Linux installs with preliminary plans to use Windows Deployment Services for Windows.

Unfortunately, we have both OSs on mixed in different subnets. Is there a way I could configure Cobbler to failover to the WDS server if it does not recognize the MAC address of the machine?

Comment: Would it be practical for you to set up a PXELinux server that would provide a menu for the user to select between getting sent to Cobbler or WDS?

Comment: We'd rather have it completely automated for obvious reasons but, if we cannot, I suppose that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out pxechain.

PXEChain allows you to chain load pxeboot environments.  I've seen this presented at some infrastructure conferences but never used it in production.

I don't know if you can set a timeout to go to the next one or not but maybe worth exploring.

http://www.vcritical.com/2011/06/peaceful-coexistence-wds-and-linux-pxe-servers/
http://blog.friocorte.com/2011/05/chain-loading-pxe-servers.html